# Use subquery columns in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this. I want to use the `PaidAmount` column to calculate another column. Is it possible?

```
SELECT 
    B.SubProjectCode, 
    A.StatementBreakDown, 
    A.Description, 
    A.ApplicableInvoices, 
    A.AgreedAmount, 
    A.SettlePercentage, 
    (A.AgreedAmount * (A.SettlePercentage/100)) DueToSettle,
    (SELECT SUM(C.PaymentAmount) FROM VendorSOAPayments C WHERE C.VendorSOAID = A.VendorSOAID ) PaidAmount, 
    (DueToSettle - PaidAmount ) BalanceAmt
FROM VendorSOA A
INNER JOIN SubProject B 
    ON A.SubProjectID = B.SubProjectID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  Select *,(DueToSettle - PaidAmount ) BalanceAmt 
   from    
    (SELECT 
        B.SubProjectCode, 
        A.StatementBreakDown, 
        A.Description, 
        A.ApplicableInvoices, 
        A.AgreedAmount, 
        A.SettlePercentage, 
        (A.AgreedAmount * (A.SettlePercentage/100)) DueToSettle,
        (SELECT SUM(C.PaymentAmount) FROM VendorSOAPayments C WHERE C.VendorSOAID = A.VendorSOAID ) PaidAmount
      FROM VendorSOA A
      INNER JOIN SubProject B 
      ON A.SubProjectID = B.SubProjectID) as Main
```

Comment: This seems to be most elegant way I think.. thanks for the Idea.

Answer (score 3):

Use common table expression (CTE), it will not harm performance.

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    B.SubProjectCode, 
    A.StatementBreakDown, 
    A.Description, 
    A.ApplicableInvoices, 
    A.AgreedAmount, 
    A.SettlePercentage, 
    (A.AgreedAmount * (A.SettlePercentage/100)) DueToSettle,
    (SELECT SUM(C.PaymentAmount) FROM VendorSOAPayments C WHERE C.VendorSOAID = A.VendorSOAID ) PaidAmount, 
    (DueToSettle - PaidAmount ) BalanceAmt
  FROM VendorSOA A
  INNER JOIN SubProject B 
  ON A.SubProjectID = B.SubProjectID
)
SELECT
   SubProjectCode, 
   StatementBreakDown, 
   Description, 
   ApplicableInvoices, 
   AgreedAmount, 
   SettlePercentage, 
   DueToSettle,
   PaidAmount, 
   (DueToSettle - PaidAmount ) BalanceAmt
 FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a temporary table/view with "With" clause and use the column from that table to calculate your another column

```
with temp as 
(SELECT 
    B.SubProjectCode, 
    A.StatementBreakDown, 
    A.Description, 
    A.ApplicableInvoices, 
    A.AgreedAmount, 
    A.SettlePercentage, 
    (A.AgreedAmount * (A.SettlePercentage/100)) DueToSettle,
    (SELECT SUM(C.PaymentAmount) FROM VendorSOAPayments C WHERE C.VendorSOAID = A.VendorSOAID ) PaidAmount,     
FROM VendorSOA A
INNER JOIN SubProject B 
    ON A.SubProjectID = B.SubProjectID)
select 
    SubProjectCode, 
    StatementBreakDown, 
    Description, 
    ApplicableInvoices, 
    AgreedAmount, 
    SettlePercentage,
    DueToSettle,
    PaidAmount,
    (DueToSettle - PaidAmount ) as BalanceAmt
from temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `APPLY`.

`CROSS APPLY` works like an `INNER JOIN`, i.e. must return a result from the subquery otherwise the entire row is discarded. There's always going to be a row for the `DueToSettle` value so it's safe to use that here.

`OUTER APPLY` works like a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, which is what I've used in the second query selecting from a separate table:

```
SELECT 
    B.SubProjectCode, 
    A.StatementBreakDown, 
    A.Description, 
    A.ApplicableInvoices, 
    A.AgreedAmount, 
    A.SettlePercentage, 
    DueToSettle.SettleAmount,
    Payments.PaidAmount, 
    (DueToSettle.SettleAmount - Payments.PaidAmount ) BalanceAmt
FROM VendorSOA A
INNER JOIN SubProject B 
    ON A.SubProjectID = B.SubProjectID
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(A.AgreedAmount * (A.SettlePercentage/100))) DueToSettle(SettleAmount)
OUTER APPLY 
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(C.PaymentAmount) 
  FROM VendorSOAPayments C 
  WHERE C.VendorSOAID = A.VendorSOAID
) Payments(PaidAmount);
```